# Website opening from WiFi but not LAN

Tags: wifi, router, lan

Can't access few websites through LAN port of my WiFi router. It's Tp-Link TLWR841N. I can access all website through WiFi. There is nothing blocking the sites on my PC as I have been using this PC for a long and my earlier router had no such issues. Also I am using Bandwidth Control for the router for a specific WiFi device.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Might be a DNS problem through LAN, try using another DNS Ip if possible.

Comment: I tried to change default DHCP Ip range from 192.168.0.110 to 192.168.0.209. But did't worked. My PC lan TCP/Ipv4 is set to automatic.

Comment: Thanks for the advice. Changing IP address did helped. You are great!